# How to generate time and date in C# and format it for mysql?

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I want to know how to generate time and date in C#  then format that value to Mysql.

Mysql supports this format: `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

More information -  I am importing datetime from mysql, and saving it in sqlite as Text  I want to update datetime in sqlite when a event happens, then I sync data back to mysql.

What is the best format to run queries in sqlite on datatime?

I would like to keep the same format: `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

Does it need to be converted to anything else native to C# or and Sqlite Database and then converted back to mysql data when synced?

Just looking for the best option.

Comment: Don't deal with these `datetime` vlaues in C# as strings, just use the [parametrized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wce29x9.aspx) to do so and it will do all the work of conversion and formatting.

Comment: Hum, I have no idea, I looked at the link you posted, is there some example code you could link to?  Thanks

Comment: if you want to store the date in the database but visually display DateTime AM/PM look at the other example below.. also I would take Mahmoud Gamal's advice and user paramerized queries

Comment: @DavidEaton - Parametrized queries, in general, are a good practice when dealing with databases. In your case, when dealing with datetime values when inserting or updating, you won't need to wary about the formatting and conversions of datetiems, It will do all the work. The link in my previous comment you will find all methods that you can use for this. You can also see [**this tutorial**](http://www.vistadb.net/tutorials/insertrows-csharp.aspx) for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For first question you could use

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;              
    string format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";   
    var mytime = time.ToString(format);
```

Comment: @DavidEaton do you mean removing AM PM from "DateTime time" or "var mytime" ?

Comment: Yea.. I deleted the comment because I was doing a messagebox with time.toString() which bypassed the format, I caught it and changed it and it works great!

Answer (score 2):

if you want to capture AM/PM try something like this with one line of code

```
string timString = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
```

> Output "2012-12-29 11:52:54 AM"

if you want to Omit the AM/PM then do the following

```
string timString = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

> Output "2012-12-29 11:52:54 "